# Unable to create AWS Rekognition project in Console nor cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-rekognition

I have followed the [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/customlabels-dg/cp-create-project.html) on how to create an AWS Rekognition custom labels project.

- In the console, I am unable to see, as mentionned, the points 2, 3 and 4:

  2. In the left pane, choose Use Custom Labels. The Amazon Rekognition Custom Labels landing page is shown.
  3. Choose Get started.
  4. Choose Create Project.
     [image: Rekognition page Screenshot]
- In the cli, I am able to make a call to the API and have a prediction on an image in my bucket.

  - But if I try `aws rekognition create-project --project-name my-project`, I get an error `An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateProject operation`.
  - I have tried with both root user and  a newly created user with permissions **AmazonRekognitionFullAccess** and **AdministratorAccess** and my credentials are set as well.
  - I used `aws configure` and correctly passed my access key, secret key and region. I checked it in `~/.aws/credentials` and `~/.aws/config`.

Don't know what I am missing here, any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message posted, even though you mention that the IAM user has the required permissions, it still points towards insufficient permissions or maybe incorrect region. To debug try the following:

- Execute the [get-caller-identity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/get-caller-identity.html) CLI command to check whether the credentials used are for the IAM user with the `AmazonRekognitionFullAccess` policy attached.
- Verify that you are invoking the command in a [region where Rekognition Custom Labels is available](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rekognition_region.html#rekognition_region).

  > Amazon Rekognition Custom Labels is available in US East (N. Virginia), US East (Ohio), US West (Oregon), and Europe (Ireland).

Comment: In the setup, they say `For information about the AWS Regions that support Amazon Rekognition Custom Labels, see Amazon Rekognition Endpoints and Quotas.` and when  I followed the link I assumed I could pick any of the list which I did but it is true that they say `Amazon Rekognition Custom Labels is available in US East (N. Virginia), US East (Ohio), US West (Oregon), and Europe (Ireland)`. I should have read more carefully. I can't believe I spent so much time on this. Thx for your help @Paradigm.

Comment: And also, their error message in the API is unclear as it refers to an AccessDeniedException

Comment: @Jones glad that helped! Agreed that the `AccessDeniedException` does throw you off thinking the user has insufficient permissions. I've learnt to check for the correct regions and availability of a feature as well, when I see that error.